# Caching options in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: caching, asp.net-web-api, cachecow

Why doesn't Web API come with caching features like MVC actions?
Is it because these are HTTP based services so no state in between calls?

I have seen a few open sources like CacheCow and Strathweb, but not sure whom to pick and why?
What are the best and standard options for caching with ASP.NET Web API?

Comment: If you are looking for HTTP Caching, have a look at (CacheCow)[https://github.com/aliostad/CacheCow].

Answer (score 2):

This is an extensive article that explains the principal options, and contains links to many more information:

[EXPLORING WEB API 2 CACHING](http://damienbod.wordpress.com/2014/05/18/exploring-web-api-2-caching/)

It includes information about:

- [CacheCow](https://github.com/aliostad/CacheCow), explained also in this [article by Scott Hanselmman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeekASPNETWebAPICachingWithCacheCowAndCacheOutput.aspx).
- [AspNetWebApi-OutputCache](https://github.com/filipw/AspNetWebApi-OutputCache)
- Your own implementation

The poor man's implementation consist in:

- implement a cache store that supports storing and retrieving values by key
- generate a key from the request properties, like action parameters, method, headers, and so on, to generate a key
- check if a value for that key is available in the cache store:

  - if it is available, return it
  - if it isn't generate it, store it and return it

  var result = cacheStore.GetValue(keyFromRequest);
  if (result == null)
  {
      result = MyClass.ExpensiveFunctionCall(params);
      cacheStore.Store(keyFromRequest, result);
  }
  return result;

The cache store can be, for example, a database, a memory cache like [MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx) class, or a [Redis](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjNvLDuj4TOAhUG7hoKHbvbDBIQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fredis.io%2F&usg=AFQjCNEFTgaheZpu4Uelg-emd65Kjv8pbg&sig2=xQPNCa-3VyR93oIvDlacHQ&bvm=bv.127521224,d.d2s) server.

The evolution of this idea is to use [MVC action filters](https://damienbod.com/2014/01/04/web-api-2-using-actionfilterattribute-overrideactionfiltersattribute-and-ioc-injection/) to make this cache cheking automatic, or to use a fully implemented solution like the aforementioned CacheCow

Comment: Could you help me out in this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26398129/caching-search-result-in-web-api

Comment: Will a database as a cache store not violate of definition of a cache which is there to prevent database queries at the first place!

Comment: @user1451111 No. A cache is something able to return a value in a faster or "cheaper" way that the usual method you'd use to get it. In your example , memory is faster than DB. But imagine you need to serve a request involving complicated calcultaions and queries to several external services. In that case getting the data from the DB is much faster than the original method to get it.