# Caching search result in Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, asp.net-web-api, http-caching

I am caching **Get** method in webapi with [strathweb](https://github.com/filipw/AspNetWebApi-OutputCache/blob/master/README.md),now i want to use same cached output in my another webapi method **Search**.So how to access cached Get result in Search Method?How to find Cache Key to use it in another methods?

```
    [CacheOutput(ClientTimeSpan = 300, ServerTimeSpan = 300)]
    public IEnumerable<Movie> Get()
    {
        return repository.GetEmployees().OrderBy(c => c.MovieId);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using the `OutputCache`, you could consider using [`MemoryCache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx) to store your results in memory for faster access.

You can store the results in cache (taking example from the following : http://www.allinsight.de/caching-objects-in-net-with-memorycache/

```
//Get the default MemoryCache to cache objects in memory
private ObjectCache cache; = MemoryCache.Default;
private CacheItemPolicy policy;

public ControllerConstructor()
{
    cache = MemoryCache.Default;

    policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
    policy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(30);
}

public IEnumerable<Movie> GetMovieBySearchParameter(string searchstr)
{
    if (cache.Get(searchstr) != null)
    {
        return cache.Get(searchstr) as IEnumerable<Movie>;
    }

    // Do the search and get the results.
    IEnumerable<Movie> result = GetMovies(blah.....);

    // Store the results in cache.
    cache.Add(searchstr, result, policy);
}
```

The above is very rough (I don't have VS in front of me right now to try it), but hopefully the core idea comes across.

http://www.allinsight.de/caching-objects-in-net-with-memorycache/

Comment: is it right to use caching in the my scenario because there could be numerous search strings and isn't it would be take much memory?

Comment: This is something you may need to try out and see what happens. IT really depends on your scenario. You could limit the number of items stored in cache, so that not every search string is saved. It's an option to look into, if it does not work for you, no worries.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to go about this would be to add OutputCache attribute to your controller. It is supported only in MVC controllers. For Web API controllers, you can use this - https://github.com/filipw/AspNetWebApi-OutputCache

The below will cache the results per search term for 24 hours. However, this method is naive and works only if the number of search terms are really small. If the number of search terms is large (as would be in this case), it adds enormous memory pressure, which will cause the ASP.NET app pool to recycle, so you will lose the cache.

```
[OutputCache(Duration=86400, VaryByParam="searchstr")] // for MVC
[CacheOutput(ClientTimeSpan = 50, ServerTimeSpan = 50)] // for Web API
[ActionName("Search")]
public IEnumerable<Movie> GetMovieBySearchParameter(string searchstr)
{           
}
```

In your case the whole result set can be cached once and can be updated every 24 hours. You can look at System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache. It supports an expiration date and a callback function when the item is removed from the cache. You can add the movie list to the cache and then query the cache. Just make sure to refresh/re-populate the cache when the items expire.

```
System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache.Add(
                key,
                value,
                null,
                expiration,
                Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
                CacheItemPriority.Normal,
                callback);
```

I would add a CachedRepository decorator to the repository which you reference in the controller. In that cached repository, I'd try to return data from the cache if it is there. If not I would fetch and return data from the original source and also add it to the cache.

Comment: Does WebAPI supports for the OutputCache attribute?

Comment: Ah, correct. Its not built in, you need this package - https://github.com/filipw/AspNetWebApi-OutputCache

Comment: i have edited my question,Is it good approach to call Get from Search,Since Get is already cached?Could you briefly tell me the solution in above context

Comment: No, that won't do it. It only works if the method is invoked through the pipeline. However, you can always refer to the cache directly - var cache = Configuration.CacheOutputConfiguration().GetCacheOutputProvider(Request); cache.Get("key"); The key is derived from the controller action name.

Comment: how to know keyname in above method>

Comment: It is controllerName.actionName - in lowercase. The logic is in MakeBaseCacheKey() method here - https://github.com/filipw/AspNetWebApi-OutputCache/blob/master/src/WebAPI.OutputCache/CacheOutputConfiguration.cs