# Cache object with ObjectCache in .Net with expiry time

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, caching, asmx

I am stuck in a scenario.
My code is like below :

**Update : its not about how to use data cache, i am already using it and its working , its about expanding it so the method don't make call between the time of expiry and getting new data from external source**

```
object = (string)this.GetDataFromCache(cache, cacheKey);

if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(object))
{
  // get the data. It takes 100ms
  SetDataIntoCache(cache, cacheKey, object, DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(500));
}
```

So user hit the cache and get data from it if the item expire it calls and get the data from service and save it in case , t**he problem is , when ever there is a pending request ( request ongoing  ) the service send another request because the object is expired  . in final there should be max 2-3 calls/ seconds and there are 10-20 calls per seconds to external service .**

Is there any optimal way to doing it so no conflict between requests time other then creating own custom class with arrays and time stamps etc?

btw the saving code for cache is-

```
private void SetDataIntoCache(ObjectCache cacheStore, string cacheKey, object target, DateTime slidingExpirationDuration)
{
  CacheItemPolicy cacheItemPolicy = new CacheItemPolicy();

  cacheItemPolicy.AbsoluteExpiration = slidingExpirationDuration;
  cacheStore.Add(cacheKey, target, cacheItemPolicy);
}
```

Comment: Check this. I think it will solve your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26581065/memory-cache-in-web-api

Comment: hi , at least what i understand , i am already using the class and its working fine , its not about how to use it , also updated my question

Comment: @kawafan, Answer suggested by Kari is correct, Lazy<T> supports singleton execution and it manages locking. It is not about using class or enumerable, it is about using Lazy<T>.

Comment: i will try the all methods posted here and will tell the results , thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have adapted the solution from [Micro Caching in .NET](http://www.superstarcoders.com/blogs/posts/micro-caching-in-asp-net.aspx) for use with the `System.Runtime.Caching.ObjectCache` for [MvcSiteMapProvider](https://github.com/maartenba/mvcsitemapprovider). The full implementation has an `ICacheProvider` interface that allows swapping between `System.Runtime.Caching` and `System.Web.Caching`, but this is a cut down version that should meet your needs.

The most compelling feature of this pattern is that it uses a lightweight version of a lazy lock to ensure that the data is loaded from the data source only 1 time after the cache expires regardless of how many concurrent threads there are attempting to load the data.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Caching;
using System.Threading;

public interface IMicroCache<T>
{
    bool Contains(string key);
    T GetOrAdd(string key, Func<T> loadFunction, Func<CacheItemPolicy> getCacheItemPolicyFunction);
    void Remove(string key);
}

public class MicroCache<T> : IMicroCache<T>
{
    public MicroCache(ObjectCache objectCache)
    {
        if (objectCache == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("objectCache");

        this.cache = objectCache;
    }
    private readonly ObjectCache cache;
    private ReaderWriterLockSlim synclock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim(LockRecursionPolicy.NoRecursion);

    public bool Contains(string key)
    {
        synclock.EnterReadLock();
        try
        {
            return this.cache.Contains(key);
        }
        finally
        {
            synclock.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }

    public T GetOrAdd(string key, Func<T> loadFunction, Func<CacheItemPolicy> getCacheItemPolicyFunction)
    {
        LazyLock<T> lazy;
        bool success;

        synclock.EnterReadLock();
        try
        {
            success = this.TryGetValue(key, out lazy);
        }
        finally
        {
            synclock.ExitReadLock();
        }

        if (!success)
        {
            synclock.EnterWriteLock();
            try
            {
                if (!this.TryGetValue(key, out lazy))
                {
                    lazy = new LazyLock<T>();
                    var policy = getCacheItemPolicyFunction();
                    this.cache.Add(key, lazy, policy);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                synclock.ExitWriteLock();
            }
        }

        return lazy.Get(loadFunction);
    }

    public void Remove(string key)
    {
        synclock.EnterWriteLock();
        try
        {
            this.cache.Remove(key);
        }
        finally
        {
            synclock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }


    private bool TryGetValue(string key, out LazyLock<T> value)
    {
        value = (LazyLock<T>)this.cache.Get(key);
        if (value != null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private sealed class LazyLock<T>
    {
        private volatile bool got;
        private T value;

        public T Get(Func<T> activator)
        {
            if (!got)
            {
                if (activator == null)
                {
                    return default(T);
                }

                lock (this)
                {
                    if (!got)
                    {
                        value = activator();

                        got = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

## Usage

```
// Load the cache as a static singleton so all of the threads
// use the same instance.
private static IMicroCache<string> stringCache = 
    new MicroCache<string>(System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache.Default);

public string GetData(string key)
{
    return stringCache.GetOrAdd(
        key,
        () => LoadData(key),
        () => LoadCacheItemPolicy(key));
}

private string LoadData(string key)
{
    // Load data from persistent source here

    return "some loaded string";
}

private CacheItemPolicy LoadCacheItemPolicy(string key)
{
    var policy = new CacheItemPolicy();

    // This ensures the cache will survive application
    // pool restarts in ASP.NET/MVC
    policy.Priority = CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable;

    policy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(1);

    // Load Dependencies
    // policy.ChangeMonitors.Add(new HostFileChangeMonitor(new string[] { fileName }));

    return policy;
}
```

> **NOTE:** As was previously mentioned, you are probably not gaining anything by caching a value that takes 100ms to retrieve for only 500ms. You should most likely choose a longer time period to hold items in the cache. Are the items really that volatile in the data source that they could change that quickly? If so, maybe you should look at using a `ChangeMonitor` to invalidate any stale data so you don't spend so much of the CPU time loading the cache. Then you can change the cache time to minutes instead of milliseconds.

Comment: hi , yes , actually these are the exchange prices , and its changes like at 200ms , and i have approx 500 requests coming per seconds to get it . cpu usage is not a problem i have a 64 core server running on this project and i touch maximum 7-8% load on peak hours

Answer (score 6):

Use [Double-checked locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) pattern:

```
var cachedItem = (string)this.GetDataFromCache(cache, cacheKey);
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(object)) { // if no cache yet, or is expired
   lock (_lock) { // we lock only in this case
      // you have to make one more check, another thread might have put item in cache already
      cachedItem = (string)this.GetDataFromCache(cache, cacheKey); 
      if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(object)) {
          //get the data. take 100ms
          SetDataIntoCache(cache, cacheKey, cachedItem, DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(500));
      }
   }
}
```

This way, while there is an item in your cache (so, not expired yet), all requests will be completed without locking. But if there is no cache entry yet, or it expired - only one thread will get data and put it into the cache.
Make sure you understand that pattern, because there are some caveats while implementing it in .NET.

As noted in comments, it is not necessary to use one "global" lock object to protect every single cache access. Suppose you have two methods in your code, and each of those methods caches object using it's own cache key (but still using the same cache). Then you have to use two separate lock objects, because if you will use one "global" lock object, calls to one method will unnecessary wait for calls to the other method, while they never work with the same cache keys.

Comment: It is important to emphasize here that the `_lock` defines the granularity for concurrency; often, the same cache object holds a range of unrelated and non-competing data, so it may be necessary to ensure that the lock granularity reflects the data.

Comment: In .NET Framework 4.0, the Lazy<T> class was introduced, which internally uses double-checked locking by default

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use locking to make sure request is not send when cache is expired and another thread is getting it from remote/slow service, it will look something like this (there are better implementations out there that are easier to use, but they require separate classes):

```
private static readonly object _Lock = new object();

...

object = (string)this.GetDataFromCache(cache, cacheKey);

if(object == null)
{
   lock(_Lock)
   {
        object = (string)this.GetDataFromCache(cache, cacheKey);
        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(object))
        {
           get the data // take 100ms
           SetDataIntoCache(cache, cacheKey, object, DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(500));
        }
   }
}

return object;
```

Also, you want to make sure your service doesn't return null as it will assume that no cache exists and will try to get the data on every request. That is why more advanced implementations typically use something like CacheObject, which supports null values storage.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, 500 milliseconds is too small time to cache, you will end up lots of CPU cycle just to add/remove cache which will eventually remove cache too soon before any other request can get benefit of cache. You should profile your code to see if it actually benefits.

Remember, cache has lot of code in terms of locking, hashing and many other moving around data, which costs good amount of CPU cycles and remember, all though CPU cycles are small, but in multi threaded, multi connection server, CPU has lot of other things to do.

Original Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16446943/85597

```
private string GetDataFromCache(
            ObjectCache cache, 
            string key, 
            Func<string> valueFactory)
{
    var newValue = new Lazy<string>(valueFactory);            

    //The line below returns existing item or adds 
    // the new value if it doesn't exist
    var value = cache.AddOrGetExisting(key, newValue, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMilliseconds(500)) as Lazy<string>;
    // Lazy<T> handles the locking itself
    return (value ?? newValue).Value;
}


// usage...


object = this.GetDataFromCache(cache, cacheKey, () => {

      // get the data...

      // this method will be called only once..

      // Lazy will automatically do necessary locking
      return data;
});
```