# Why do I need to call twice the Set on my size limited MemoryCache when I hit the size limit?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, memorycache

We are about to use the built-in in-memory cache solution of ASP.NET Core to cache aside external system responses.  (We may shift from in-memory to `IDistributedCache` later.)
We want to use the [Mircosoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/)'s `IMemoryCache` as the [MSDN suggests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

We need to limit the size of the cache because by default it is unbounded.
So, I have created the following POC application to play with it a bit before integrating it into our project.

#### My custom MemoryCache in order to specify size limit

```cs
public interface IThrottledCache
{
    IMemoryCache Cache { get; }
}

public class ThrottledCache: IThrottledCache
{
    private readonly MemoryCache cache;

    public ThrottledCache()
    {
        cache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions
        {
            SizeLimit = 2
        });
    }

    public IMemoryCache Cache => cache;
}
```

#### Registering this implementation as a singleton

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddSingleton<IThrottledCache>(new ThrottledCache());
}
```

I've created a really simple controller to play with this cache.

#### The sandbox controller for playing with MemoryCache

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class MemoryController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache cache;
    public MemoryController(IThrottledCache cacheSource)
    {
        this.cache = cacheSource.Cache;
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Get(string id)
    {
        if (cache.TryGetValue(id, out var cachedEntry))
        {
            return Ok(cachedEntry);
        }
        else
        {
            var options = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions { Size = 1, SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1) };
            cache.Set(id, $"{id} - cached", options);
            return Ok(id);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see my `/api/memory/{id}` endpoint can work in two modes:

- Retrieve data from cache
- Store data into cache

---

I have observed the following strange behaviour:

1. GET `/api/memory/first`
   1.1) Returns `first`
   1.2) Cache entries: `first`
2. GET `/api/memory/first`
   2.1) Returns `first - cached`
   2.2) Cache entries: `first`
3. GET `/api/memory/second`
   3.1) Returns `second`
   3.2) Cache entries: `first`, `second`
4. GET `/api/memory/second`
   4.1) Returns `second - cached`
   4.2) Cache entries: `first`, `second`
5. GET `/api/memory/third`
   5.1) Returns `third`
   5.2) Cache entries: `first`, `second`
6. GET `/api/memory/third`
   6.1) Returns `third`
   6.2) Cache entries: `second`, `third`
7. GET `/api/memory/third`
   7.1) Returns `third - cached`
   7.2) Cache entries: `second`, `third`

As you can see at the 5th endpoint call is where I hit the limit. So my expectation would be the following:

- Cache eviction policy removes the `first` oldest entry
- Cache stores the `third` as the newest

But this desired behaviour only happens at the 6th call.

So, my question is why do I have to call twice the `Set` in order to put new data into the MemoryCache when the size limit has reached?

---

**EDIT**: Adding timing related information as well

During testing the whole request flow / chain took around 15 seconds or even less.

Even if I change the `SlidingExpiration` to 1 hour the behaviour remains exactly the same.

Comment: Third _won't_ be added to the cache, the cache is full with "first" and "second". After a minute after adding the "first" entry to the cache, it expires and new items can be added. At least, that's how I guess it works, going to find the docs...

Comment: Yeah, see duplicate: "An entry will not be cached if the sum of the cached entry sizes exceeds the value specified by SizeLimit". So it's not the second call you need, it's the time between the calls.

Comment: @CodeCaster The whole request flow took around 15 seconds. If I change the `SlidingExpiration` to 1 hour it behaves in the exact same way.

Comment: I've updated it accordingly.

Comment: How do you observe the cached entries?

Comment: @Eldar I've used the debugger to scrutinize the `cache`'s `_entires` field.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I [downloaded](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/building/windows-instructions.md), [built](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/docs/workflow/building/libraries/README.md) and debugged the unit tests in [Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/src/MemoryCache.cs); there seems to be no test that seems that truly covers this case.

The cause is: as soon as you try to add an item which would make the cache go over capacity, [MemoryCache triggers a compaction](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/src/MemoryCache.cs#L215) in the background. This will evict the oldest (MRU) cache entries up until [a certain difference](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/src/MemoryCache.cs#L386). In this case, it tries to remove a total size of 1 of cache items, in your case "first", because that was accessed last.

However, since this compact cycle runs in the background, and the code in the `SetEntry()` method is [already on the code path for a full cache](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/src/MemoryCache.cs#L210), it continues without adding the item to the cache.

The next time it tries to, it succeeds.

Repro:

```
class Program
{
    private static MemoryCache _cache;
    private static MemoryCacheEntryOptions _options;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _cache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions
        {
            SizeLimit = 2
        });

        _options = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions
        {
            Size = 1
        };
        _options.PostEvictionCallbacks.Add(new PostEvictionCallbackRegistration
        {
            EvictionCallback = (key, value, reason, state) =>
            {
                if (reason == EvictionReason.Capacity)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Evicting '{key}' for capacity");
                }
            }
        });
        
        Console.WriteLine(TestCache("first"));
        Console.WriteLine(TestCache("second"));
        Console.WriteLine(TestCache("third")); // starts compaction

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        Console.WriteLine(TestCache("third"));
        Console.WriteLine(TestCache("third")); // now from cache
    }

    private static object TestCache(string id)
    {
        if (_cache.TryGetValue(id, out var cachedEntry))
        {
            return cachedEntry;
        }

        _cache.Set(id, $"{id} - cached", _options);
        return id;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I've read the [following section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-3.1#additional-notes) I thought if the expiration check needs direct interaction then eviction should have as well. (And as you have revealed indeed the trigger of compaction is  the `SetEntry`). My naive thought was eviction is a synchronous operation...  Can I detect somehow capacity overflow?  This feels a bit strange for me `// The entry was not added due to overcapacity` `entry.SetExpired(EvictionReason.Capacity);` an exception might be better here IMO

Comment: _"Can I detect somehow capacity overflow?"_ - I don't think so, apart from using reflection. _"an exception might be better here IMO"_- I don't think adding an item to a cache should involve exceptions in this case.

Comment: Thanks for all the effort you put into.

Comment: This should be added to MS official documentation if not already there. It helped me understand how compaction and eviction works.